# how to create nested folders using aws cli in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

In linux to create nested folders, irrespective of the intermediate folders exist or not can be done using the below command.

```
mkdir -p /home/user/some_non_existing_folder1/some_non_existing_folder2/somefolder
```

Similar to this i want to create a nested folder structure in S3 and place my files there later

how can i do this using `aws cli`

Comment: Do you know what folders in S3 are? Either they are just logical groupings because files exist under them or they are 0-byte objects with a trailing / in their key. In the first case you need to do nothing for nested "folders", in the second case *you* need to manually put all the nested folders there yourself. Why do you need folders in the first place? What is the goal?

Comment: I want to keep the same folder structure.

Comment: because we have to copy lot of folder there. and it will be quite confusing to track.

Comment: is there anyway to do this without manually creating nested folders..

Comment: I would suggest you **just upload a single nested file** right now and see how S3 works, in particular how it decides to display folders.

Answer (score 1):

Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3.

For example, if you have an empty bucket you could upload a file to `invoices/january.txt` and the `invoices` folder will magically 'appear' without needing to be specifically created.

Then, if you were to delete the `invoices/january.txt` object, then the `invoices` folder will magically 'disappear' (because it never actually existed).

This works because the `Key` (filename) of an Amazon S3 object **contains the full path of the object**. The above object is *not* called `january.txt` -- rather, it is called `invoices/january.txt`. The Amazon S3 console will make it appear as if the folder exists, but it doesn't.

If you click the **Create folder** button in the S3 management console, then a zero-length object is created with the name of the folder. This causes the folder to 'appear' because it contains a file, but the file will not appear (well, it does appear, but humans see it as a folder). If this zero-length object is deleted, the folder will 'disappear' (because it never actually existed).

Therefore, if you wish to create a directory hierarchy before uploading files, you could **upload zero-length objects with the same names as the folders you want to create**. You can use the `aws s3 cp` command to upload such a file.

Or, just **upload the files to where you *want* them to appear**, and the folders will magically appear automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
  # create bucket

  aws s3 mb s3://main_folder


  # created nested folder
  aws s3api put-object --bucket main_folder --key nested1/nested2/nested3/somefoldertosync

  # sync my local folder to s3

  aws s3 sync /home/ubuntu/somefoldertosync s3://main_folder/nested1/nested2/nested3/somefoldertosync
```

currently i am using the above way to carry on with my work